# Django query get common items based on attribute

Tags: django, django-queryset, set-theory

I have a model as follows:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    VENDOR_CHOICES = (
        ('a', 'A'),
        ('b', 'B')
    )

    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=VENDOR_CHOICES)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

Now I have 2 data sources, so I get items from vendor A and items from vendor B.

In some cases vendor A may not have the same items as Vendor B, say vendor A has 30 items and Vendor B has 442 items, out of which only 6 items are common. Items that are common are defined as items that have the exact same name.

I need to also find the difference in prices of items that are common to vendor a and vendor b items, meaning the items that have the same name in vendor a and vendor b. I have a large no. of items which may go upto 10k items per vendor, so a efficient way of doing this would be required?

Comment: Starting from version 1.11, django query sets have a builtin intersection and difference method. I have added it as an answer for future reference

Answer (score 1):

I think that something like this should work:

```
vendor_a_items = Item.objects.filter(vendor='a')
vendor_b_items = Item.objects.filter(vendor='b')

common_items = vendor_a_items.filter(
                       name__in=vendor_b_items.values_list('name', flat=True))
```

**UPDATE**: To find the price difference you can just loop over the found common items:

```
for a_item in common_items:
    b_item = vendor_b_items.get(name=a_item.name)
    print u'%s: %s' % (a_item.name, a_item.price - b_item.price)
```

This adds a db hit for each found item but if you have a small number of common items then this solution will work just fine.  For larger intersection you can load all prices from `vendor_b_items` in one query.  Use this code instead of the previous snippet.

```
common_items_d = {item.name: item for item in common_items}
for b_item in vendor_b_items.filter(name__in=common_items_d.keys()):
    print u'%s: %s' % (b_item.name,
                      common_items_d[b_item.name].price - b_item.price)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, just one more thing, can I find the difference in the price from the common items?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from [django 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#intersection), this can be resolved using the built in intersection and difference methods.

```
vendor_a_items = Item.objects.filter(vendor='a')
vendor_b_items = Item.objects.filter(vendor='b')
common_items = vendor_a_items.intersection(vendor_b_items)
vendor_a_exclussive_items = vendor_a_items.difference(vendor_b_items)
vendor_b_exclussive_items = vendor_b_items.difference(vendor_a_items)
```

See my [blog post](http://technowhisp.com/2017/08/08/django/django-orm-union-intersection-and-difference/) on this for more detailed use cases.